# Marklogic cts:element-child-geospatial-query is slow but does not need index?

Tags: search, twitter, marklogic

Hi Markloggers out there,

I bump into a strange situation.
My experience so far is that I need to set a specific index for cts: functions to perform well. Now I need to search geotagged tweets in de db I use the following query.
Seems I do not need teo make specific indexes for cts:element-child-geospatial-query() to run, but performance is poor... what am I missing here?

Query

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
declare namespace j = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic";

let $lon := 5.470047
let $lat := 51.819565
let $radius := 5.0

let $point := cts:point($lon, $lat)

let $circle := cts:circle($radius,$point)
(:
let $pattern := "/twitter/*"         
let $pointSource := cts:uri-match($pattern)  
:)

(: give back all tweet ids in the circle :)
let $codes := for $p in cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:element-child-geospatial-query(xs:QName("j:geo"), xs:QName("j:point"), $circle))
    return $p//j:id

return fn:count($codes)
```

One million tweets that have to following elements in them:

```
<json type="object" xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
... other stuff ...
<dikwmetadata type="object">
<source type="string">
twitter_nederland
</source>
<timestamp type="string">
2014-03-11T21:19:03.818547
</timestamp>
<data xmlns:j="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/json/basic">
<point_was_tried>
2014-03-11T21:19:03.835457+01:00
</point_was_tried>
<postalcode_was_tried>
2014-03-11T21:19:03.835457+01:00
</postalcode_was_tried>
<geo lastupdate="">
<point>
4.65407742 , 52.28828829
</point>
</geo>
<tags lastupdate=""/>
<postalcodes lastupdate="">
<postal_code>
2135
</postal_code>
</postalcodes>
</data>
</dikwmetadata>
</json>
```

we added element range index type = string to geo and point elements but no improvement...

Response now 60 seconds...

Any tips?

hugo

Comment: You could try using https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:query-trace to debug it. You should be able to see whether or not the geo index is used. But if your search matches 1M documents and you are counting all of them, 60-sec sounds pretty decent. Maybe introduce pagination?

Answer (score 2):

Geospatial indexes are separate from range indexes. You can create them in Admin > Databases > DB-Name > Geospatial Indexes.

In addition to running the query unfiltered, if you simply want to count the number of matching fragments, then you can use `xdmp:estimate` instead of `count`:

```
xdmp:estimate(cts:search(...))
```

Comment: Well spotted: I missed that it was a range index not a geo index.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider doing the cts:search unfiltered.
cts:search(fn:doc(), cts:element-child-geospatial-query(xs:QName("j:geo"), xs:QName("j:point"), $circle),("unfiltered"))
That would go by the indexes only instead of actually verifying each hit.